# Email from the application is not working from glassfish 6.0.0 due to conflict of javax mail library

Tags: glassfish, jakarta-mail

Email from the application is not working from glassfish 6.0.0 due to conflict of javax mail library with the glassfish 6 mail libraries from a modules folder.

We have REST application implemented using jersey 3.0.0 deployed on glassfish 6. We are using log4j for logging.
When there is an error, it failed to send the email. I tried the same application from localhost using tomcat it is sending an email.

This is what I added to my pom.xml

-- Jakarata.mail (1.6.5) jar file and log4j(1.2.17)

I also tried replacing log4J 1.2.17 to log4j2.17.1
I keep getting ClassCastException or ClassNotFoundException or NoSuchMethodError.
With Jakarta.mail.jar I am receiving below error
**java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain cannot be cast to javax.activation.DataContentHandler**

```
        I tried replacing Jakarta.mail.jar with (com.sun.mail) javax.mail.jar 1.6.2        
       
            I received below error
            **ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender LogToMail org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.mail.util.MimeUtil.cleanContentType**

            Tried with mail.jar 1.4.7 instead of javax.mail.jar  and activation.jar(1.1.1) 

        Getting below Error
        **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.mail.util.PropUtil.getBooleanSessionProperty**
        
        As there is already some other mail library there in classloader I removed the mail library from the application then I am getting 

        **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
        I tried copying jakarata.mail and jakarata.activation.jar under glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext folder but got NOSTMP provider**. 
        
        If I copy javax.mail.jar and activation.jar under glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext folder then same error **“ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender LogToMail org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.mail.util.MimeUtil.cleanContentType”**
        
        I also tried adding mail.jar and activation.jar under glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext folder
        **ERROR Caught exception while sending e-mail notification.: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: smtp**
```

I refer to the below link. Not completely understood what xbootclasspath does but tried adding the below lines to domain.xml.

[DCH class error with JavaMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521027/dch-class-error-with-javamail)
-Xbootclasspath/p:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/modules/jakarta.mail.jar

-Xbootclasspath/p:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/modules/jakarta.activation.jar

if anyone is able to successfully send an email from glassfish 6.0.0

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish already included Jakarta Mail. There's no need to include it in your pom. When you do, it will conflict, as you per the errors you got.

Comment: Thanks, Arjan for the reply. I tried removing all the mail jars from my application then  I am getting No SMTPProvider found. It is not getting mail jar from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Jakarata.mail 1.6.5 which you use in your application is old, it uses the javax.mail package prefix. GlassFish 6 uses the jakarta package prefix. You should upgrade to jakarta.mail-api 2.1.0 and use it only for compilation, don't add it to your application WAR (provided scope):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```